# ASP.NET WebForms: Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath() returns empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, seo, friendly-url

I have got simple ASP.NET WebForms project with only few pages and I would like to use friendly URLs (not only for SEO but also localization of URLs). I use .NET 4.5 for this project and have tried to use Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls nuget package which looked like it might help. But there is one issue.

I've got in Global.asax this:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

and RouteConfig class looks like this:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("HowItWorks", "ako-to-funguje", "~/HowItWorks.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("AboutUs", "o-nas", "~/AboutUs.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("Contact", "kontakt", "~/Contact.aspx");

        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

I want to show the same page if you access it through both /HowItWorks and /ako-to-funguje (which is Slovak locale).

And now I am getting close to actual issue. When I access site with one of localized routes (e.g. /ako-to-funguje) then Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath() returns empty string (but I want to get "~/HowItWorks.aspx" upon which I want to do some stuff in master page).

```
 string pageFileName = Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath();
 switch (pageFileName)
 {
      case "~/AboutUs.aspx":
           //do some stuff
           break;
      case "~/HowItWorks.aspx":
           //do some stuff
           break;
      case "~/Contact.aspx":
           //do some stuff
           break;
      default:
           break;
 }
```

If I access site with /HowItWorks URL then Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath() returns "~/HowItWorks.aspx" as expected.

Any idea how to get "~/HowItWorks.aspx" from Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath() when accessing site through both /HowItWorks and /ako-to-funguje?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I've come up with own workaround of this issue. I've created own extension method for http request which returns virtual file path to currently executed page:

```
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Routing;
 using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;

 namespace Utils.Extensions
 {
      public static class HttpRequestExtensions
      {
          public static string GetFileVirtualPathFromFriendlyUrl(this HttpRequest request) 
          {
             string ret = string.Empty;

             ret = request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath();

             if (ret == string.Empty)
             {
               foreach (RouteBase r in RouteTable.Routes)
               {
                   if (r.GetType() == typeof(Route))
                   {
                       Route route = (Route)r;
                       if ("/" + route.Url == request.Path)
                       {
                           if (route.RouteHandler.GetType() == typeof(PageRouteHandler))
                           {
                               PageRouteHandler handler = (PageRouteHandler)route.RouteHandler;

                               ret = handler.VirtualPath;
                           }
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
             }

             return ret;
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Petriq, This is a great solution.  I have been trying to find a way of resolving a similar problem for several days (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/22577826/236860) and this works perfectly.

Comment: This does not work if you have parameters in the url or if your using a virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

Please check with

```
string requestUrl = this.Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath().ToLowerInvariant();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUrl)) {
   requestUrl = this.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated Petriq's answer to handle parameters in the url

```
public static string GetFileVirtualPathFromFriendlyUrl(this HttpRequest request) {
        string ret = request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath();

        if (ret == string.Empty) {
            for(int j = 0, a = RouteTable.Routes.Count; j<a;j++) {
                RouteBase r = RouteTable.Routes[j];
                if (r.GetType() == typeof(Route)) {
                    Route route = (Route)r;

                    StringBuilder newroute = new StringBuilder(route.Url);
                    if (route.Defaults != null && route.Defaults.Count > 1) {
                        string[] keys = route.Defaults.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
                        foreach (string k in keys) { 
                            newroute = newroute.Replace("{" + k + "}", k.CheckQueryString()); 
                        }
                    }

                    if (String.Compare(newroute.ToString(), request.Path.Replace(request.ApplicationPath, ""), true) == 0) {
                        if (route.RouteHandler.GetType() == typeof(PageRouteHandler)) {
                            PageRouteHandler handler = (PageRouteHandler)route.RouteHandler;
                            return handler.VirtualPath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The Routes can now be

```
RouteValueDictionary contactDefault = new RouteValueDictionary { { "person", UrlParameter.Optional } };

routes.MapPageRoute("Contact", "kontakt/{person}", "~/Contact.aspx");
```